# Mark all object properties, including nested objects as required

Tags: joi

Is there a way to do it by default? And not by hand for every property?

If it's possible, i hope it can be done in Joi.default

```
const joi = Joi.defaults((schema) => {
  return schema.strict().options({ stripUnknown: true })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way, you can use presence('required'):

```
import Joi from '@hapi/joi'

const joi = Joi.defaults((schema) => {
  return schema
    .strict()
    .options({ stripUnknown: true })
    .presence('required')
})

export { joi }
```